# Why is the code on a contract address different from the compiled code?

Tags: contract-deployment

There seem to be clear differences between the hex that the solidity compiler spits out and the hex that is displayed by eth.getCode() after you have published the contract.

for example the original output starts with ('|' used do delineate the differences)

`60606040523|4610000575b61116b806100196000396000f30060606040523|61561006b576000357c010`

whereas the submitted contract starts with a shortened

`6060604052361561006b576000357c010`

Does anyone know what causes this discrepancy?